# Check for duplicates in each loop in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, loops, ember.js, filtering

I have a very simple template loop:

```
{{#each}}
     {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

Fact is, my `title` can appear in my data multiple times (of course other parts of the record change) but I want to make sure that there are no duplicates for a given property (in this case `title`). Is there any way to put some logic inside the template to make sure to exclude duplicates?

I tried using an Handlebar Helper, but I really didn't make much progress with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put a computed property on the controller that's backing the template.  Ember has a method `uniq` that will return the unique items in the array.

```
uniqueItems: function(){
  return this.get('model').getEach('title').uniq();
}.property('model.@each.title')
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IMOMoliB/5/edit

Comment: Thank you again for dropping by. That's great, except that I need to check for no duplicates **on a given property**. [In this JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IMOMoliB/3/edit), for example, I might want to show only one from `color: red` or only one from `type: pants`.

Comment: You're getting into filtering type concepts, getEach is really useful for grabbing all of a single property off a collection of models.

Comment: Do you mean I should use `.getEach(prop).uniq()` as a computed property? Would that be the best approach to do that? [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IMOMoliB/7/edit) **EDIT:** Nevermind, just noticed your edit. :)

Comment: BTW, I just updated the dependent property as well, it wouldn't get updated if one of the title's changed before.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Your answer certainly got me going, but with this method I am left with an array of values, though in my case I need the entire object to be preserved. This is what I mean: [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IMOMoliB/8/edit).

Comment: There is a pull request that might make this easier, https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3696#issuecomment-27800587 until that comes out though you'd have to manually do it http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IMOMoliB/9/edit .  Which seems a little weird to me, because one red shirt isn't necessarily more correct than the red pants, it just came earlier in the list, so it doesn't necessarily make sense to me, but I probably don't completely know your problem.

Comment: That issue sounds great. Thank you for your pointer: indeed my example sounded weird, but I think it kinda made sense in my situation. :)